# Why is there no preposition behind the word "mile"?

Tags: prepositions

> The region is some 40 miles north of Seoul.

What does it mean? I personally think it means "The region is 40 miles away from the north of Seoul".

Why is there no preposition after the word *mile*?

Comment: I have edited your question now, because I think you are not really looking for the meaning, rather the reason into why there is not a preposition after _miles_. Am I correct?

Comment: Yeah..I thought the grammar/syntax using around a word could also get involved in the USAGE..sorry my bad.

Answer (score 5):

I think maybe you are parsing the sentence wrong:

> (The region) (is) (about 40 miles north) (of Seoul).

I say this because you're asking why there is no preposition after *miles*, yet the word *of* is right there (albeit after the word *north*).

As a picture, it would look like this:
[image: about 40 miles north]
In English, we typically can append a direction onto a distance to describe a vector:

> The cabin is **about 2 miles south** of the lake.
>   Leominster is **about 50 miles west** of Boston.

When the direction is omitted, a preposition might follows the unit, or we might use the word *away* followed by the preposition:

> The store is about 3 kilometers from here.
>   The star is about 43 light years away from earth.

Answer (score 2):

The word north has been used in the sentence as an adverb that means "toward the north".

The region is north. It implies that the region is towards the north.

The region is north of Seol. It means that the region is towards the north of Seol.

The region is some 40 miles north of Seol. It means that the region is  some 40 miles (away) towards the north of Seol.

Answer (score 1):

"..North of..." **is** the preposition in the sentence.

In English, "North of" can roughly be swapped with the common preposition "above" when referring to points on a map.

> The region is some 40 miles **North of** Seoul.
>
> The region is some 40 miles **to the North of** Seoul.
>
> The region is some 40 miles **above** Seoul.
>
> The region is some 40 miles **away from** Seoul.

You'll see that all of the above examples are prepositions.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right but to paraphrase the original sentence, it would mean:

> The region is approximately 40 miles to the north of Seoul.

*Some* in this sentence means it is approximately.

Comment: Why there is no any preposition behind the word"miles"?

Comment: "to the" (in "40 miles to the north") is optional and may be omitted without changing the meaning of the sentence.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yes i have noted that but I am explaining this in the most simplistic way I can so he could fully understand this sentence.

Comment: But I should not ommit "to the" when it comes to formal writting, right? It only can be acceptable in spoken english, right?

Comment: @오준수 - The "to the" is not required, even in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. When the distance between to locations that are not singular points (e.g. a city) is given, the usual interpretation is that the distance is measured more-or-less from the center of the location. For a city, it might be the "central business district" or some other commonly accepted central location.

I would expect few people to interpret the statement as being in relation to some northerly extremity of the city (so it is not "40 miles away **from the north** of Seoul").

P.S. the word "some" implies the speaker is only estimating the distance (i.e. it is not exactly 40 miles)

Comment: Why there is no any preposition behind the "miles"? You know , mile is a noun..

Comment: It doesn't need any. What preposition are you thinking of?

Comment: Like "from"..or "to"

Answer (score 0):

"Some" defines quantity, but in this case it also gives an approximation (on how far away the region is from Seoul), so you are partially right.